# Proof $2^{1092}-1$ is divisible by $1093^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like a proof that $2^{1092}-1$ is divisible by $1093^2$. I can prove it is divisible by $1093$ by using Fermat ($1093$ is a prime) or Euler. However I'm pretty sure we are going to have to look at more things to crack this one. I also tried to write $1093$ in binary $10001000101$ and see if it has multiples made entirely of ones, but that didn't work either. Thank you very much.

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Daniel Fischer and others in the chat I now have a viable solution by a procedure known as exponentiation by squaring:

$2^{17}= 131072\leadsto (2^{17})^2= 2^{34} \equiv 816564\equiv -378085 \leadsto$

$(2^{34})^2=2^{68}\equiv 1042817\equiv -151832 \leadsto$

$(2^{68})^2=2^{136}\equiv 1009120\equiv -185529 \leadsto$

$(2^{136})^2=2^{272}\equiv 782853 \leadsto$

$2^{272}\cdot 2=2^{273} \equiv 371057 \leadsto$

$(2^{273})^2=2^{546}\equiv 1194648\equiv-1 \leadsto$

$(2^{546})^2=2^{1092}\equiv 1 \bmod 1093^2$. As desired.

Comment: Very nice!  It is interesting to note that the original can be divided up a bit; $$2^{1092}-1=(2^{273}-1)(2^{273}+1)(2^{546}+1)$$ and since these three terms are pair wise relatively prime then $1093$ and also $1093^2$ can only divide one of them.  You found that $1093^2\mid 2^{546}+1$, it is also possible to break this down further as $2^{546}+1=(2^{182}+1)(2^{364}-2^{182}+1)$ and find that $1093^2\mid 2^{182}+1$.

Comment: My approach would have been to break down each of the pieces up to the cubic form ($(a\pm 1)(a^2\pm a+1)$) and then modularly exponentiate up to one of the base terms ($2^{91}$) and see what I could find...